# Modulo in custom class

Tags: java, math

I am working on something that requires me to use very large numbers, so I am  making my own number class. Now one of the math operations that is completely necessary is the modulo operation, and I do not know of a way to do this. My class consists of an ArrayList of integers in reverse order, ex the number 5321 would look like 1235.

Comment: Why you reinvent the wheel? Can't you use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` classes? Also if you have problems with code then post it.

Comment: for in the future I want to know how it works, and if I made the class I know how it would work

Comment: @Slymodi then you should also look at the source code for `BigInteger`  and `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember modulo is the remainder. Posted below is some psudo code on how this could be done assuming you have a + operator and a - operator for your number class.

```
BigNum operator%(BigNum divisor)
{
    BigNum val = this;
    BigNum div = divisor;
    while(div < val)
    {
        div = div + divisor;
    }   

    return this - (div - divisor);
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't directly support operator overloading so the operations would have to be functions